# screen /bin/bash execute script and then go to interactive shell

Tags: bash, scripting, byobu

I am using .byobu/windows to start up some screen sessions, and I'm trying to start a script that will exit to an interactive shell once it has completed. Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
screen -t test /bin/bash -i /path/to/script
screen -t test /bin/bash - /path/to/script
```

I realize I could just add a /bin/bash to the end of the script, but I don't want that as a solution for when I run the script in a shell...

Comment: What does the script you want to run before the command prompt do?

Answer (score 2):

If it's important to use the same shell use the `--rcfile` flag.

```
$ cat test.bashrc 
ls
PS1='TEST \$'
$ screen -t test bash --rcfile test.bashrc -i
a.file  b.file  test.bashrc
TEST $
```

If your `.bashrc` is setting the environment, be sure to source it.

Answer (score 2):

The only reasonable way that I've found to run a command, leaving the output and an interactive shell behind within screen is to use the 'stuff' command to execute the command:

```
screen -t title1 bash
stuff 'ls /tmp^M'  # in vim type control-v control-m to insert the return at the end
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, just start two commands.

```
screen -t test /bin/bash /path/to/script; /bin/bash
```

If you are only able to start one command, try this:

```
/bin/bash -c 'screen -t test /bin/bash /path/to/script; /bin/bash'
```